# #ifdef is returning different values inside the same header file

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

I have two C++ files `main.cpp` and `client.cpp`, and a header file `action.h`. I am trying to mimic a simple client-server scenario using preprocessor directives. The code is as follows:

```
//main.cpp
#include "action.h" 
extern void connect(); 
static Action server; 
int main()
{
    server.init(); 
    connect(); 
    server.execute(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

```
//client.cpp
#define CLIENT 
#include "action.h" 
void connect()
{
    Action client; 
    client.init(); 
    client.execute(); 
}
```

And the header file.

```
#include <iostream>
struct Action
{
    #ifdef CLIENT
    int data = 10;
    #else
    int data = 13; 
    #endif
    inline void init()
    {
        #ifdef CLIENT
        std::cout << "Client " << data << std::endl;
        data = -1;
        #else
        std::cout << "Server " << data << std::endl;
        data = 0;
        #endif
    }
    inline void execute()
    {
        #ifdef CLIENT
        std::cout << "Server is " << data << std::endl;
        #else
        std::cout << "Number of clients is " << data << std::endl;
        #endif
    } 
};
```

When I run this, I get the following result:

> Server 13
>
> Server 10
>
> Number of clients is 0
>
> Number of clients is 0

Now my question is why is the `#ifdef CLIENT` block executing in the declaration section of `action.h` `(int data = 10)` while the `#else` block is executing inside the `init()` and `execute()` functions when I call them from `client.cpp` file? Why are not all three calls going to the `#ifdef` part?

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of violating the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule)

Comment: Having two different definitions of the class `Action` violates the one definition rule. The behavior of the program is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program exhibits undefined behavior. It violates the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule) (ODR). Specifically this part:

> **[basic.def.odr]/6** There can be more than one definition of a class type, ... inline function with external linkage ... in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. Given such an entity named `D` defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> (6.1) — each definition of `D` shall consist of the same sequence of tokens...
> ...
>
> If the definitions of `D` do not satisfy these requirements, then the behavior is undefined.

In your case, you have two definitions of class `Action` as well as its inline member functions `Action::init` and `Action::execute`, that consist of different sequence of tokens, thanks to macro trickery.